# How can i send email weekly every user in asp.net core 2.2 i have done with asp.net mvc using global file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to send my all register user weekly news letter so i need to send email for every week after deploying server by automatic process but i can't find in asp.net core 2.2 how can i do this before i done this same thing in asp.net Mvc with global file but i can't understand in core how can i do this please give me some helpful solution.
Email code working find

```
  public bool SendEmail(string email, string subjec, string body, string name)
    {
        try
        {
            string senderMail = "*****";
            string senderPass = "*****";
            string MailHostServer = "*******";
            string port = "587";
            string displayName = "Account Activation";

            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.From = new MailAddress(senderMail, displayName);

            mail.To.Add(email);
            mail.Subject = subjec;

            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mail.Body = body;


            mail.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;

            var stmp = new SmtpClient();
            stmp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(senderMail, senderPass);
            stmp.Host = MailHostServer;
            stmp.Port = Convert.ToInt32(port);
            stmp.EnableSsl = true;
            stmp.Send(mail);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            return false;
        }


    }
```

Comment: https://www.hangfire.io/

Comment: Windows Scheduled Task

Comment: thankyou @stuartd i have done with hangfire its easy and work prefect.

Comment: @HamzaShafiq good news :)

Answer (score 1):

Besides hangfire, you could also use [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#timed-background-tasks)

If you would like to run it at specific time, you could use:

```
public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var currentTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

            //run background task at Monday 11:00:00
            if (currentTime.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday && currentTime.Hour == 11 && currentTime.Minute == 0 && currentTime.Second == 0)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation(currentTime.ToString());
                DoWork();
            }

        }
   }
```

For consuming dbcontext in hosted service:

[How should I inject a DbContext instance into an IHostedService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48368634/how-should-i-inject-a-dbcontext-instance-into-an-ihostedservice)

For how to start and stop it manually:

[ASP.NET Core IHostedService manual start/stop/pause(?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51469881/asp-net-core-ihostedservice-manual-start-stop-pause)

Comment: thank you for your help but i have done with the hangfire using 
            RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<UserMail>(
            salesReport => salesReport.ForAllCustomers(), Cron.Weekly);

Answer (score 0):

If you are run on windows machine, you can use Windows Scheduled Task.

Or please check this link.

[C# console app to send email at scheduled times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18858512/c-sharp-console-app-to-send-email-at-scheduled-times)